# attr_accessor not updating value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class with attribute accessors:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize
    @a = 1
    @b = 2
  end

  def update_values options
    a = options[:a]
    b = options[:b]
  end
end
```

I think that after calling `update_values`, `a` and `b` should retain their new values:

```
describe MyClass do
  before do
    @thing = MyClass.new
  end

  it 'should set a and b' do
    expect(@thing.a).to eq 1
    expect(@thing.b).to eq 2
    @thing.update_values a: 2, b: 5
    expect(@thing.a).to eq 2
    expect(@thing.b).to eq 5
  end
end
```

This is not happening - the test fails:

```
Failures:

  1) MyClass should set a and b
     Failure/Error: expect(@thing.a).to eq 2

       expected: 2
            got: 1

       (compared using ==)
```

Isn't this how attribute accessors should work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just defining local variables `a` and `b`.

What you want instead, is to set new values for instance variables `a` and `b`. Here is how you can do that:

```
def update_values options
  self.a = options[:a] # or @a = options[:a]
  self.b = options[:b] # or @b = options[:b]
end
```

Now:

```
foo = MyClass.new
#=> #<MyClass:0x007f83eac30300 @a=1, @b=2>
foo.update_values(a: 2, b: 3)
foo #=>#<MyClass:0x007f83eac30300 @a=2, @b=3>
```

Comment: I was thinking that because attr_accessor adds the a= and b= methods to the class that their action on 'self' would be implicit - but I guess it's a Ruby parsing thing. = as an assignment operator takes precedence over = in a method name. thanks!

Comment: If one questions what Andrey is saying, add the line `p "local variables = #{local_variables}"` at the end of (the original) `initialize`. When `foo = MyClass.new` is invoked, `"local variables = [:a, :b]"` is displayed.